# Fewer FIO output. Update in the same line

Tags: benchmarking

After reading fio manual and researching for quite some time, I still do not know the answer. Please help if you know the trick:

Is there an option I can choose in fio so that it doesn't print a new line of progress every second?

```
[root@localhost fio]# fio test.fio
raw=random-read: (g=0): rw=randread, bs=8K-8K/8K-8K/8K-8K, ioengine=libaio, iodepth=16
fio-2.2.9
Starting 1 process
Jobs: 1 (f=1): [r(1)] [5.0% done] [2023MB/0KB/0KB /s] [259K/0/0 iops] [eta 0
Jobs: 1 (f=1): [r(1)] [6.7% done] [2016MB/0KB/0KB /s] [258K/0/0 iops] [eta 0
Jobs: 1 (f=1): [r(1)] [8.3% done] [2018MB/0KB/0KB /s] [258K/0/0 iops] [eta 0
....
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit old, but the solution is simple:  make your terminal wider and it won't do that.